# Visual Studio 2017 doesn't recognize system variables

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 to compile an OpenCL program. I've installed the GPUOpen OpenCL SDK to `C:\Program Files (x86)\OCL_SDK_Light` with the system variable `OCL_ROOT` pointing to that directory. However, Visual Studio doesn't seem to recognize the variable when I add it to Additional Include Directories. `%OCL_ROOT%` is being treated as a literal string while `$(OCL_ROOT)` doesn't resolve to anything. Only when I use the full file path does Visual Studio recognize the library.

Does Visual Studio not support Windows system variables? Or do I simply have the syntax wrong?

Comment: How did you set the system variable?

Comment: @KenWhite The variable was set by the SDK installer. It definitely works in cmd. `echo %OCL_ROOT%` will print `C:\Program Files (x86)\OCL_SDK_Light`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently restarting my computer solved the problem. No idea why Visual Studio didn't recognize the variable even though other programs did.